# Packaging login flow OR connecting a login flow to profile programmatically in Post Installation Script

Tags: apex, profile, visual-workflow, visual-flows, loginflow

I have created a Login flow in my Dev org. When I packaged and deployed it on another org I noticed that Flow is created but there is nothing under Login Flow.

The question is that how can we package a login flow so that it's available there in the packaged org OR how can we programmatically connect a flow to a profile in Post Installation scripts?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include Login Flows in packages. See [list of components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_component_behavior.htm) that can be added to packages. Also there is no way to create login flow pragmatically using post installation scripts.

Login flow is a custom process invoked when a user logs in. For that, you need to manually create a login flow and associate it with needed profiles. Since you successfully deployed flow, you can manually [create a login flow and connect to profiles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_login_flow_associate.htm&type=0&language=en_US).